# Semantic Maps are just not working

Tags: maps, mediawiki

It's idiotic question, sorry. But I spent 2 days... and still no result.
May be you can help me.

1. I have installed media wiki [here](http://azbyka.ru/palomnik/), version 1.25.1.
2. I have Semantic MediaWiki, Semantic Maps, Maps extensions, you can see it [here](http://azbyka.ru/palomnik/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) (it's russian, but you still can see titles & versions).
3. And I just copied example from [here](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_Maps_examples/Query_by_category).

So, here is the [city](http://azbyka.ru/palomnik/TempMoscow), that using [template](http://azbyka.ru/palomnik/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD:Location).

And [page with "ask, format map"](http://azbyka.ru/palomnik/TempCategory):, just like this:

```
{{
#ask:
[[Category:Locations]]
| ?Has coordinates
| format=map
}}
```

Nothing more. It must work, why not?
Single maps are working fine. But `ask` with `format map` — no. It renders just `<p><br/></p>`.

Why, why, why?

Comment: Your syntax is ok, so you will have to troubleshoot on your side. Start by enabling error logging

Comment: @leo, thank you for the answer. Still doing it. No errors, nothing. In debug process now. So strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just didn't make "Has coordinates" real geo-property. I have not very big practice with mediawiki + SWM, but it was not really clear for me.

What I had to do:

1. Create a page for this property (`Property:Has coordinates`).
2. Make it semantic geo-property: just write inside: `[[Has type::Geographic coordinate|]]`.

That's it.
Thank you!